# ECM on extremely big numbers?

Tags: number-theory

Denote the following recursion

$$a(0):=0 , a(n+1):=a(n)^2+1$$

I search a prime factor of a(89). There is none below 1,5*10^9. As the number
 itself is far too big, ECM cannot be used directly. But perhaps, there is a
 trick to enable it. The only restriction for the prime factors, which I know,
 is that every prime divisor of a(89) must be equal to 1 modulo 4. Perhaps,
 someone finds better restrictions to accelerate the search.

Comment: a(1)=1 , a(2)=2 , a(3)=5 , a(4)=26 , a(5)=677 and so on.

Comment: The sequence is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A003095 and maybe some of the references given there would be helpful. But I suspect that neither ECM nor any other method will be any good here. Though you might tell us how you know there are no factors below $1.5\times10^9$.